# SSH and services are only listening on Wi-Fi interface when Ethernet cable is unplugged

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am working with a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Buster Lite. The RPi is connected via `eth0` to a hardwired Ethernet network (LAN1) and via the `wlan0` interface to a Wi-Fi network (LAN2).

When the Ethernet cable is connected, I can take another host on LAN1 and SSH into the Pi's LAN1 IP address. But I cannot take a host on LAN2 and SSH into the Pi's LAN2 IP address.

But when I disconnect the Ethernet cable, after a second I *can* SSH into the Pi's LAN2 IP address. And as soon as I re-attach the Ethernet cable, the wireless SSH connection dies.

The `wlan0` interface appears to remain up even when the Ethernet cable is attached (the RX/TX packet counts do increase). And the Raspberry Pi is able to ping hosts both on LAN1 and LAN2.

How can I make SSH accessible on both Ethernet and Wi-Fi simultaneously?

Comment: What does netstat tell us ?  run it when connected by wifi and not by wifi and look for port 22 .maybe also show the routing table and interface states in both states

Comment: What network addresses are used for both interfaces?